# dropdown menu with multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I'm figuring out how I can use a dropdown menu that will auto fill other cells with the right information.   For example i made a nutrition calculator but I'm tired of filling in by hand every time. So my question is , is there a possibility to make a dropdown menu where you can choose an ingredient ( like my example "wortel" = carrot ) and that sheets automatically fills in the other things like kcal/vet/verz etc. etc.. Off course I know I have to make an ingredient list my self first but then I only have to fill it in once instead of every time.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give you a specific formula to use without having the actual data sheet, but I can give you a method you could use.

I'll give you an example of how to do this with a mock set up for your ingredient list.

---

Assume that your ingredient sheet looks like this:

| Item | KCAL | VET | VERZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carrot | cKCAL | cVET | cVERZ |
| Tomato | tKCAL | tVET | tVERZ |

etc. etc. and is named `Ingredients`.

In your lookup sheet that you posted in your question, you could set the formula in cell `C3` to be the following:

`=iferror(filter(Ingredients!B2:D22, Ingredients!A2:A22=A3:A23))`

---

Please let me know if you have any trouble with this. Hope this helps!